# How can i check whether an event is in a sigma-algebra generated by multiple random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In my Probability-Theory course we had the proof of a theorem (Kolmogorov's inequality) and i got stuck at one point...

Let's say for the sake of this question that we consider a simple random walk, i.e. $X_i,1\leq i\leq n$, independent random variables, s.t.

$$P[X_i=1] = P[X_i=-1]=\frac 12$$

We defined events ($u\gt 0$ is a given real number)
$$1 \leq k \leq n :A_k:=\{|S_k|\geq u:|S_j|\lt u \; \forall j\lt k \} = \{first\; time \;j\; at \;which\;|S_j| \ge u\; is \;exactly\; k\}$$
Now in the proof it is claimed without further explanation that  $A_k \in \sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$.

I think that intuitively this makes sense, because it can be determined whether $A_k$ happens or not by just looking at $X_1,...,X_k$. But what is the formal explanation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for each $1 \le j \le k$, we have $S_j$ is $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$-measurable because it is the sum of $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$-measurable random variables, so $|S_j|$ is also $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$-measurable for each $1 \le j \le k$.  By the definition of measurability, this implies $\{|S_j| \ge u \} \in \sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$ and $\{|S_j| < u \} \in \sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$ for all $u$ and $1 \le j \le k$.  Then

\begin{align*}
A_k = \{|S_k| \ge u \} \cap \{|S_{k-1}| < u \} \cap \cdots \cap \{|S_1| < u \}
\end{align*}

is a finite intersection of sets in $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$ and therefore is itself in $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$.